# Make DIV fixed inside a scrollable DIV

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone now how to make a DIV inside another DIV that is scroll-able fixed, so that no matter how much I scroll by, the DIV always stays in the same place?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your scrollable div ever scroll off screen?

Comment: Yes it does, its like a container held at the top of the screen and loads more information underneath it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scrollable {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #333;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    .fixed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 180px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #fa2;
    }
</style>
<div class="scrollable">
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    <div class="fixed">and I'm fixed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer from Fredrik is not accurate as `.fixed` is positioned relative to the document, not to the scrollable div. Adding `position: relative;` to the `.scrollable` will fix this issue but will make `.fixed` fixed relative to the `.scrollable` content, not to the `.scrollable` viewport, which is I believe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend absolutely positioning the div *over* the scrollable div. It wont be *in* the scrollable div, because it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using `position:sticky`. To explain, I have just copied html/css from other answers here. Obviously `position:sticky` has limited support across browsers. Please check before using this solution.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scrollable {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #333;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    .fixed {
        position: sticky;
        top: 80%;
        left: 80%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #fa2;
    }
</style>
<div class="scrollable">
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    im scrollable<br><br>
    <div class="fixed">and I'm fixed</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed div in scrollable div**

```
#container {
position:absolute;
top:150px;
left:150px;
width:600px;
height:500px;
overflow:hidden;
border:3px dashed #ffff00;
padding:0px;
}

#this_scroll {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
width:99%;
height:99%;
overflow:scroll;
border:2px solid #000;
margin:1px;
background:#B0BDCE;
}

#fix_close {
position:absolute;
top:2px;
right:21px;
width:90px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
border:2px solid #660099;
z-index:10;
background:#8C8C8C;
}


<div id="container">

    <div id="this_scroll">
    <p>some yxyxyx</p><p>some yxyxyx</p>
    </div>

    <div id="fix_close">
        close
    </div>

</div>
```